# Filter Data with Pivot Table Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to filter users based on their `subscription_status` which s stored in a pivot table.
I have Three tables `users` , `subscription_packages` , `subscription_package_user`

```
 $user=User::with(['studentDetails','subscriptionsSatus.courses'])
                        ->withPagination($offset,$perPage)
                        ->get()
                        ->sortBy('first_name')->values();
```

this code return the response is

```
 [
{
    "id": 44,
    "first_name": "Abcd Test",
    "last_name": "Test lastname",
    "student_details": null,
    "subscriptions_satus": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Gold",
            "price": 3000,
            "user_id": "2"
            "pivot": {
                "user_id": 44,
                "subscription_package_id": 1,
                "subscription_status": "on_free_trial",
                "expires_on": null,
                "id": 9
            },
            "courses": [
                {
                    "id": 18,
                    "title": "English Grammar for Class 3",
                    "price": 400,
                    "strikethrough_price": null,
                    "status": "draft",
                    "user_id": 2,
                    "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses/1615702915.png",
                    "description": null,
                    "pivot": {
                        "subscription_package_id": 1,
                        "course_id": 18,
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

i want to return only users who having `subscription_status =$filter`.

```
$filter='acive'or 'on_free_trail'
```

my model is

```
public function subscriptionsSatus()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(SubscriptionPackage::class)->withTimestamps()->withPivot('subscription_status','expires_on','id');
}
```

I havetried

```
    $filter=$request->input('filter')??"active";
$user=User::with(['studentDetails','subscriptionsStatus.courses'])
                         ->whereHas('subscriptionsStatus', function($query) use($filter){
                             $query->wherePivot('subscription_status','=',$filter);
                         })
                            ->withPagination($offset,$perPage)
                            ->get()
                            ->sortBy('first_name')->values();
```

But Got error Column not found 'pivot'

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `wherePivot` along with the `orWhere` like below:

```
public function subscriptionsStatus()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(SubscriptionPackage::class)
                    ->withTimestamps()
                    ->withPivot('subscription_status','expires_on','id')
                    ->wherePivot(function($q){
                        return $q->where('subscription_status','=','active')
                            ->orWhere('subscription_status','=','on_free_trail');
                    });
}
```

### ***Update***

***Or in your controller:***

```
$user=User::with(['studentDetails','subscriptionsStatus.courses'])
                         ->whereHas('subscriptionsStatus', function($query) use($filter){
                             $query->withPivot('subscription_status')
                                   ->wherePivot('subscription_status','=',$filter);
                         })
                            ->withPagination($offset,$perPage)
                            ->get()
                            ->sortBy('first_name')->values();
```

Comment: i want to use the query in controller since the $filter is dynamic.like if the filter has 'on_free_trail 'then return all users have free_trail otherwise return all users have "active " subscription.

Comment: can you show your blade where you want to show them? @JEJ

Comment: Sorry for late reply, did you try withPivot('....') before wherePivot() in your controller query?